# MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command - Cordova in VS2015

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am experiencing problem with MySql for my newly created demo project of Cordova in VS2015, the error says like this:

```
MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I tried to add MySql.exe path to the environment variable but it has not worked. When I googled out for the solution I got to know this:

http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/a87395a8c046/mysql-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-command-apache-cordova-for-visu.html][1](http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/a87395a8c046/mysql-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-command-apache-cordova-for-visu.html)

But it is not clear exactly where to put double quotes and any other remedy described in the link.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: If you use VS2015 and MySql you should know that VS2015 dont support MySql for now..
More info: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6893071-mysql-for-visual-studio-does-not-work-in-vs-2015-p

Comment: I just selected basic project, I haven't used mysql anywhere. However, it is true that I will need MySql but still no worried as REST is here.

Answer (score 4):

Yep did the same with the quotes. Ad the quotes to the PATH system variable.

```
control panel > system > Advanced system settings > environment variables
```

Comment: The problema comes with the MYSQL default path that includes an '&' and that does not like to the Windows. If you try to open a command window and execute echo %PATH% you will see the same message when the command window tries to show the path. Adding the quotes in the directory where appears that '&' will work: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5";"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP"